# Foreign Key Failure in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a database composed of three tables. This is my query in creating my tables with Foreign Key.

```
CREATE TABLE reporter
(
  reporterid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  firstname VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
  lastname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (reporterid)
);

CREATE TABLE flood
(
  floodid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  address VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
  dateofflood DATE NOT NULL,
  timeofflood INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (floodid)
);

CREATE TABLE reports
(
  reportid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  timereport NODATATYPE NOT NULL,
  datereport DATE NOT NULL,
  rid INT NOT NULL,
  fid INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (reportid),
  FOREIGN KEY (rid) REFERENCES reporter(reporterid),
  FOREIGN KEY (fid) REFERENCES flood(floodid)
);
```

I created a system in order for me to add records/row on my database through PHP. This is my code:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db("flooddatabase")or die("Connection Failed"); 


$description = $_POST['description'];
$address = $_POST['address']; // Make sure to clean the
$dateofflood=$_POST['dateofflood'];
$timeofflood=$_POST['timeofflood'];
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
$dateofreport=$_POST['dateofreport'];
```

$timeofreport=$_POST['timeofreport'];

```
$query = "INSERT into flood(address,description,dateofflood,timeofflood) values ('$address','$description','$dateofflood','$timeofflood')";
$query2 = "INSERT into reporter(firstname,lastname) values ('$firstname','$lastname')";
$query3 = "INSERT into reports(dateofreport,timeofreport) values ('$dateofreport','$timeofreport')";



if(mysql_query($query))
  if(mysql_query($query2))
   if(mysql_query($query3))
        {
          echo "";
        } else
        {
          echo "fail";
        }

?>
```

The result that I am getting is fine. It's just that, in my REPORTS table, there is no foreign key that is being generated. For example I input something on my reporter table and flood table, the foreign key 'rid' and 'fid' has no values that references to both tables. Need help thank you.

Comment: The last insert statement expects values of `rid` and `fid` field.

Comment: The last insert, you're saying you want to insert into 2 columns but only define one column, which isn't going to work.

Comment: Alter the primary keys of `flood` and `reporter` table to `AUTO_INCREMENT`. It's one of your tasks.

Comment: As an aside, mysql_* functions are deprecated in later PHP5 versions and removed in 7. Also, you're open to SQL injections attacks. Have a look at PDO / mysqli and prepared statements.

Comment: @JonStirling Oh yea, sorry bout that. I updated it.

Comment: @Subrata Dey Pappu Yes, I already have my floodid and reporterid auto_incremented...

Comment: But I don't see that in your table structures. @user3767918

Comment: @SubrataDeyPappu Updated it. In my local DB here, I have it auto incremented

Answer (score 0):

- Get the just inserted Primary key value from flood table insert
  query. And store it to a variable say $f_id;
- Get the just inserted primary key value from reporter table insert
  query and store it to a variable say $r_id;
- Now Make your last insert statement like below:

  `"INSERT into reports(dateofreport,timeofreport,rid,fid) values ('$dateofreport','$timeofreport',$r_id,$f_id)";`

I am not giving you a direct copy paste solution.

If you need to know how to get the last inserted id by executing an insert query then look at this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp)

Comment: I'll try this. But I have a question, in my previous experience, I had two tables one with FK and then in my query, I did not put any value to my FK but in my database, there's actually a record or value in my FK from my PK.

Answer (score 0):

> there is no foreign key that is being generated

I'm not entirely sure what you even mean by that.  *Foreign* keys aren't "generated".  *Primary* keys can be, which you do:

```
reporterid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

(as well as for your other two tables)

> the foreign key 'rid' and 'fid' has no values

Well, look at your query:

```
INSERT into reports(dateofreport,timeofreport) values ...
```

Where do you insert values for `rid` and `fid`?  I'm actually pretty surprised this query works *at all*, since those columns don't allow `NULL` values:

```
rid INT NOT NULL,
fid INT NOT NULL,
```

(Though your column names also don't line up, so I find it likely that the code you're showing isn't *actually* the code you're using...)  That point aside however, the fact still remains that if you want a value in those fields then you have to *put* a value in those fields:

```
INSERT into reports(dateofreport,timeofreport,rid,fid) values ...
```

After each query, you can get the last generated identifier from `mysql_insert_id()`:

```
$last_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Use that to then populate the values being inserted as foreign keys in subsequent queries.

---

Also worth noting, the `mysql_*` libraries are long since deprecated and have been replaced with `mysqli_` and other libraries such as `PDO`.  I highly recommend you upgrade to a current technology, since what you're using isn't supported by any vendor.

Additionally, and this is **very important**, your code is *wide open to **SQL injection attacks***.  This basically means that you execute any code your users send you.  You should treat user input as values, not as executable code.  [This](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) is a good place to start reading on the subject, as is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: The query1 and query2 works but the query3 doesn't. There's no rows added. (regarding what you said, " I'm actually pretty surprised this query works at all"

Comment: @user3767918: That would be something worth mentioning in the question.  As worded, you're implying that a row is added but those values aren't present.  If no row is added at all, then the query is definitely failing.  Note that this code doesn't check for error messages from queries, it just assumes success.  I bet the database is telling you that `NULL` values aren't allowed in those columns.

Comment: I'll try this. But I have a question, in my previous experience, I had two tables one with FK and then in my query, I did not put any value to my FK but in my database, there's actually a record or value in my FK from my PK.

Comment: @user3767918: I can't really comment on code you're not showing.  But the bottom line is that if you want a field to have a value then you need to put a value in that field.

Comment: sorry can i ask again, what do you mean by this "Use that to then populate the values being inserted as foreign keys in subsequent queries.
"

Comment: @user3767918: First you'd insert into `reporter`, then you'd get the ID which was generated from that insert, then you'd use that ID when inserting into `reports`.  (Same for getting the ID from `flood`.)  Your `reports` table requires values for `rid` and `fid`, so those are the values you need to insert into those fields.